# About a song lyric

Tags: song-lyrics

I was looking at the [lyrics](http://music.goo.ne.jp/lyric/LYRUTND365/index.html) of RCサクセション's 雨上がりの夜空に. My understanding is that this is a song about a person talking to his/her (personified) car. There are several things I don't understand.

(1) In this line

```
バッテリーはビンビンだぜ
```

I understand that バッテリー is mentioning a car battery. But why is `ビンビン` used?
Does it have any meaning related to charging of a battery?

(2) In this line

```
こんな夜に 発車できないなんて
```

The person is perhaps sad that he/she cannot ride the car. But why is `発車` (start moving with the car) used here? I guess it would be more natural to say that they cannot start the engine, but why is it particularly mentioning `発車`? Is it normal in Japanese say "I cannot start moving with the car" when they cannot start the engine or cannot go for a drive?

(3) In this line

```
雲の切れ間にちりばめたダイヤモンド
```

What is `ダイヤモンド` mentioning? I cannot make sense of a slit between the clouds being filled with a diamond. Is it some metaphor?

Comment: Songs can be abstract or poetic, so you may hear things not heard in conversational speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This song uses "double entendre" everywhere in the lyrics. The explicit context, of which you are aware, is riding a car, and the implied context is riding a woman.

I agree with you that ビンビン and 発車 sounds unnatural, when they are only talking about cars. But I hope you can easily understand what ビンビン and 発射 (the same sound as 発車) mean in the latter context.

And twinkle twinkle little stars are like diamonds in the sky --- Japanese people are familiar with that metaphor, too.